# Getting one section of a larger matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with dimensions 512 x 683 but want to get the section from 108 to 305 horizontally and 160 - 430 vertically separated so i can work on it, then replace it back into the original matrix. How would i go about removing it, and eventually reattaching it? Thanks

Comment: Can't you use indexing? `M(160:430,108:305)` or something of that kind?

Comment: What you are asking is very basic Matlab, the (generally very good) documentation will answer this question for you after about 10 minutes reading. What have you tried ?  Show us your code.

Comment: Indexing worked great, and my apologies Mark, using stackoverflow has made my intro to mat lab so much easier, and I guess I'm getting a little lazy looking up things. After I finish doing my work on this section, how would i reattach it?

Comment: How did you get the information out? What have you tried to put it back in?

Comment: I just used the indexing Schorsch recommended and created a new matrix, I tried adding it, but obviously that doesn't work as the matrices are different sizes, and adding is not even what I would like to do. The goal would be to leave all elements not within the (108:305, 160:430) range alone, and simply replace the numbers inside that range with my new numbers.

Comment: This is not directly related to the issue in this question: Looking at your track record, your questions get a lot of down-votes. This will eventually prevent you from asking more questions. Maybe consider having a look at [this website on how to ask good questions.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: I would agree with the other commenters, you should do a bit more research on your own before coming here. MATLAB's documentation is very good and usually a quick Google search will find the documentation you need. For instance, Googling "extracting submatrix MATLAB" brings up several discussions from which it should be clear how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As schorsch said in comments, simply do:

```
A=M(160:430,108:305)
```

to get values

then modify your sample ( `B=transform(A)` )

and put B in the same way you got A out

```
M(160:430,108:305)=B
```

Remember that : basically means everything in between

I agree with Mark though, the documentation for MATLAB is outstanding and one of MATLAB's best features compared to open source, utilize it please.